# isotope : replace all filter for a new category

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope

i have too many images in my gallery and i want to replace the "all" filter for "principal" and show it on the load.
I already tried to use container.isotope filter='.principal' but then nothing shows at the lading, only if i click on principal it shows the filtered results.

```js
/* Portfolio Sorting */


jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
 (function ($) { 
 
 
  var container = $('section.portfolio_container');
  
  function getNumbColumns() { 
   var winWidth = $(window).width(), 
    columnNumb = 1;
   
   
   if (winWidth > 1500) {
    columnNumb = 6;
   } else if (winWidth > 1200) {
    columnNumb = 5;
   } else if (winWidth > 900) {
    columnNumb = 4;
   } else if (winWidth > 600) {
    columnNumb = 3;
   } else if (winWidth > 300) {
    columnNumb = 2;
   }
   
   return columnNumb;
  }
  
  
  function setColumnWidth() { 
   var winWidth = $(window).width(), 
    columnNumb = getNumbColumns(), 
    postWidth = Math.floor(winWidth / columnNumb);
   
   container.find('.portfolio').each(function () { 
    $(this).css( { 
     width : postWidth + 'px' 
    });
   });
  }
  
  $('.gallerySelector .gallerySelectorList a').click(function () { 
   var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
   
   $(this).parent().parent().find('> li.current').removeClass('current');
   $(this).parent().addClass('current');
   
   container.isotope( { 
    filter : selector 
   });
   
   setTimeout(function () { 
    reArrangeProjects();
   }, 300);
   
   
   return false;
  });
  
  function reArrangeProjects() { 
   setColumnWidth();
   container.isotope('reLayout');
  }
  
  
  container.imagesLoaded(function () { 
   setColumnWidth();
   
   
   container.isotope( { 
    itemSelector : 'article.portfolio', 
    layoutMode : 'masonry', 
    resizable : false
     
   } );
  } );
  
  
 
  
 
  $(window).on('debouncedresize', function () { 
   reArrangeProjects();
   
  } );
  
 
 } )(jQuery);
} );





/* DebouncedResize Function */
 (function ($) { 
  var $event = $.event, 
   $special, 
   resizeTimeout;
  
  
  $special = $event.special.debouncedresize = { 
   setup : function () { 
    $(this).on('resize', $special.handler);
   }, 
   teardown : function () { 
    $(this).off('resize', $special.handler);
   }, 
   handler : function (event, execAsap) { 
    var context = this, 
     args = arguments, 
     dispatch = function () { 
      event.type = 'debouncedresize';
      
      $event.dispatch.apply(context, args);
     };
    
    
    if (resizeTimeout) {
     clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
    }
    
    
    execAsap ? dispatch() : resizeTimeout = setTimeout(dispatch, $special.threshold);
   }, 
   threshold : 150 
  };
 } )(jQuery);
```

```css
 
#folio {
 background:url(../images/gallery-quote.png) center 80px no-repeat #111;
 padding-top:100px;
 clear: left;
}
.portfolio_container {
 position:relative;
 display:block;
 overflow:hidden;
 width:100%;
}
.portfolio_container .portfolio {
 position:relative;
 display:block;
 float:left;
 overflow:hidden;
 width:25%;
 height:auto;
}
.portfolio_container .portfolio .media_box figure a img {
 display:block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

.portfolio_container .portfolio .media_box .hover_effect {
 top:0;
 left:0;
}

.gallerySelector {
 background: #222;
 height: 44px;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.gallerySelectorList {
 margin:0;
 width: 100%;
}
.gallerySelectorList li {
 float: left;
 margin:0;
 list-style:none;
 width: 20%;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0;
}
.gallerySelectorList li:hover {
 background: #83103e;
}

.gallerySelectorList li a {
 display:block;
 padding:11px 0;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin: 0;
 transition:background-color 0.3s ease, color 0.2s ease;
}
.gallerySelectorList li.current  {
 background: #7b133c;
}
.portfolio_container .portfolio {
    width: 20%;
}

.fullwidth {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}

#gallery h3  {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.project-title {
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-top: 7px;
}

.project-description {
 color: #868991;
 font-size: 10px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 600;
 margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.columns .overlay-content.loupe {
 width: 34px;
 height: 34px;
 background: url(../../../templates/images/loupe.png) 0px 0px no-repeat;
 position: absolute;
 top: 22%;
 margin: -17px 0 0 -17px;
 left: 50%;
 z-index: 10;
}
.thumbLink {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}
.thumbImage {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.thumbImage img{
    transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
.thumbImage .thumbText h3 {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.thumbImage .thumbText p {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 color: #fff;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.thumbImage .thumbTextWrap {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
    height: 100%;
 padding: 0 20px;
 opacity: 0;
 background: #7b133c;
 text-align: center;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.ie8 .thumbImage .thumbTextWrap {
 display:none;
}
.thumbImage .thumbTextWrap:before {
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 height: 100%;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin-right: -0.5em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}
.thumbText {
    text-align: center;
 transform: scale(0);
    transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
 display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   width: 90%;
}
.thumbImage:hover img {
 opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(10);
}
.thumbImage:hover .thumbTextWrap {
 opacity: 1;
}
.ie8 .thumbImage:hover .thumbTextWrap {
 display: block;
}
.thumbImage:hover .thumbText {
 transform: scale(1);
}
.thumbLink {
 background:url(../images/icons/icon-magnify.png) center center no-repeat #fff;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 border-radius: 15px;
 opacity: 0.5;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.thumbLink:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}
.portfolioBottom {
 background: #222;
 height: 44px;
 width: 100%;
 clear: left;
}
```

```html
   <div id="folio" class="page section">
        
     
         <div class="container">
                
                <div class="sixteen columns">
                    <h1>Portifólio</h1>
                    <h3><span class="small">Those who do</span> <span class="smallBold">not want to</span>
                    <br><span class="largeBold">imitate</span> <span class="large">anything,</span>
                    <br><span class="medium">produce</span><span class="mediumBold"> nothing.</span> 
                    <br><span class="author">Salvador Dali</span></h3>
                   
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="gallerySelector">
            <ul class="gallerySelectorList">
                <li class="current"><a data-filter="article.portfolio[data-category~='principal']" href="#">principal</a></li>
                <li><a data-filter="article.portfolio[data-category~='redacao']" href="#">Redação</a></li>
                <li><a data-filter="article.portfolio[data-category~='criacao']" href="#">Redação-Criação</a></li>
                <li><a data-filter="article.portfolio[data-category~='social']" href="#">Social Media</a></li>
                <li><a data-filter="article.portfolio[data-category~='video']" href="#">Audiovisual</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
            
        <section class="portfolio_container">
            
   <article class="portfolio" data-category="principal">
                <section class="thumbImage">
                    <img src="images/gallery/t-rec1.jpg" alt="" class="fullwidth">
                    <div class="thumbTextWrap">
                        <div class="thumbText">
                            <h3 class="sectionTitle">Gallery Item</h3>
                            <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. </p>
                            <a class="thumbLink" href="images/gallery/rec1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac augue at erat hendrerit dictum."></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </article>

            <article class="portfolio" data-category="rincipal">
                <section class="thumbImage">
                 <img src="images/gallery/t-rec2.jpg" alt="" class="fullwidth">
                    <div class="thumbTextWrap">
                        <div class="thumbText">
                            <h3 class="sectionTitle">Gallery Item</h3>
                            <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. </p>
                            <a class="thumbLink" href="images/gallery/rec2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac augue at erat hendrerit dictum."></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </article> 
            <article class="portfolio" data-category="principal">
                <section class="thumbImage">
                    <img src="images/gallery/t-rec3.jpg" alt="" class="fullwidth">
                    <div class="thumbTextWrap">
                        <div class="thumbText">
                            <h3 class="sectionTitle">Gallery Item</h3>
                            <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. </p>
                            <a class="thumbLink" href="images/gallery/rec3.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac augue at erat hendrerit dictum."></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </article>
            <article class="portfolio" data-category="redacao criacao">
                <section class="thumbImage">
                    <img src="images/gallery/t-rec4.jpg" alt="" class="fullwidth">
                    <div class="thumbTextWrap">
                        <div class="thumbText">
                            <h3 class="sectionTitle">Gallery Item</h3>
                            <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. </p>
                            <a class="thumbLink" href="images/gallery/rec4.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac augue at erat hendrerit dictum."></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </article>
            <article class="portfolio" data-category="redacao criacao">
                <section class="thumbImage">
                    <img src="images/gallery/t-rec5.jpg" alt="" class="fullwidth">
                    <div class="thumbTextWrap">
                        <div class="thumbText">
                            <h3 class="sectionTitle">Gallery Item</h3>
                            <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. </p>
                            <a class="thumbLink" href="images/gallery/rec5.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac augue at erat hendrerit dictum."></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </article>
            <article class="portfolio" data-category="redacao criacao">
                <section class="thumbImage">
                    <img src="images/gallery/t-rec6.jpg" alt="" class="fullwidth">
                    <div class="thumbTextWrap">
                        <div class="thumbText">
                            <h3 class="sectionTitle">Gallery Item</h3>
                            <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. </p>
                            <a class="thumbLink" href="images/gallery/rec6.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac augue at erat hendrerit dictum."></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </article>
            <article class="portfolio" data-category="video">
                <section class="thumbImage">
                    <img src="images/gallery/videothumb.png" alt="" class="fullwidth">
                    <div class="thumbTextWrap">
                        <div class="thumbText">
                            <h3 class="sectionTitle">Gallery Item</h3>
                            <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. </p>
                            <a class="thumbLink" href="http://youtu.be/3UkU2I7OVB4" rel="prettyPhoto" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac augue at erat hendrerit dictum."></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </article>
            <article class="portfolio" data-category="redacao criacao">
                <section class="thumbImage">
                    <img src="images/gallery/t-rec7.jpg" alt="" class="fullwidth">
                    <div class="thumbTextWrap">
                        <div class="thumbText">
                            <h3 class="sectionTitle">Gallery Item</h3>
                            <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. </p>
                            <a class="thumbLink" href="images/gallery/rec7.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac augue at erat hendrerit dictum."></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </article>
            <article class="portfolio" data-category="redacao criacao">
                <section class="thumbImage">
                    <img src="images/gallery/t-rec8.jpg" alt="" class="fullwidth">
                    <div class="thumbTextWrap">
                        <div class="thumbText">
                            <h3 class="sectionTitle">Gallery Item</h3>
                            <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. </p>
                            <a class="thumbLink" href="images/gallery/rec8.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac augue at erat hendrerit dictum."></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Done! all had to do is, instead of filter: '.principal' i had to use

`filter: "article.portfolio[data-category~='principal']"`

weeeeeeeee o/o/o//oo/